# Email is not send in my server

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have go daddy hosting and user sing up email is not send. I have used `mail()` function.
Which method I use and also how email send if user sing up?
Like `mail("abc@yahoo.com", $subject, $message, $headers);`
I am using PHP language.

In response to a comment, here's the code:

```
$to = 'aaas@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'welcome';
$message = 'xxxxxxxxxx ' . "\n" ;
$headers = 'From: AAA' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: No Reply' . "\r\n";
$mailed = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Can you post code where you send the mail?

Comment: $to      = 'aaas@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'welcome';
$message = 'xxxxxxxxxx ' . "\n" ;
$headers = 'From: AAA' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: No Reply' . "\r\n";
     
$mailed=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: Are you using sendmail? It would be good to know what mail server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`AAA` is not a valid `from` address. You need a full, valid E-Mail address that resolves to the domain you are sending the mail from.

`reply-to: No Reply` is also unlikely to work.